# How do I force the refresh of a ResourceData object?

Tags: resourceobject

The following code will read the cases of COVID around the world to be used later for analysis.
This is in a notebook that I use to check the status of the pandemic on a daily basis.

When opening the file the following day, the ResourceData is not updated with the latest data.

```
covid = ResourceData[ResourceObject[
Association[Rule["Name","Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"],Rule["UUID","dba89a96-2b3a-4254-8824cb1f9e01a94b"],
Rule["ResourceType","DataResource"],Rule["Version","112.0.0"],Rule["Description","Tracking the Novel Coronavirus (COVID-19) Global Cases"],
Rule["RepositoryLocation",
URL["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/resourcesystem/api/1.0"]],
Rule["WolframLanguageVersionRequired","10.0"],Rule["ContentSize",Quantity[2.935288`,"Megabytes"]],Rule["ContentElements",
List["AustraliaProvinces","CanadaProvinces","ChinaProvinces","Dataset","USCounties","USStates","WorldCountries"]]]]

covid[1]
(*values from previous day*)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to force the refresh by searching for the resource first.

```
ResourceSearch["covid"];
covid=ResourceData[...];
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation you can use the `ResourceUpdate` function which updates the `ResourceObject`.

See [`ResourceUpdate` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceUpdate.html) and [Wolfram Data Repository](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframDataRepository.html).